# convert std::vector<T> into Dataset^

Tags: c++, c++11, dataset, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I have a vector of c++ structs, and I need to put this into a managed, typed dataset.

```
std::vector<Record*> record_collection;

class Record{
public:
Record(){};
virtual ~Record(){};
virtual void serialize(std::ostream& dest){
    dest << "Record" << std::endl;
}
};
```

Record* is a base class - I need to handle the derived class.  A typical example is

```
class TestRecord:public Record{
public:
    TestRecord(){};
    ~TestRecord(){};
    std::string t_str;
    int t_int;
    double t_double;
    void serialize(std::ostream& dest){
        dest << t_int << ',' << t_double << ',' << t_str << ',' << std::endl;
    };
};
```

Essentially, I need to reproduce the serialize method, except that I need to make DataColumns for `t_str`, `t_int`, and `t_double`, type the columns appropriately, and then put the values in them.

I can edit anything as required at this point, but I need to set up the pattern such that anything that implements record can have its data members can be serialized into a managed dataset with typed columns.

Can anyone advise on a pattern, or a suggestion, that would help?  I could do it with inspection on a tuple if this were Python, but in c++11 a tuple needs to be of predefined type.

The problem here is that I may not compile record or TestRecord with /cli, in which case I could pass in the datatable to the record and let it populate it itself - so I'm looking for a better solution than the ones I have:

a) Write a managed wrapper for *every* derived class
b) Do type inspection.

Is there a pattern I've missed?

Thanks,
Melanie

Comment: Is `serialize` `virtual`? How many child classes? Is the number fixed and never changing? Can you change the child classes? Can you change the `Record` class? Give an example concrete interface for `Record`. You say you need to reproduce `serialize` with `DataColumn`s, but you also say you need `Dataset^` -- which do you actually need?

Comment: Good questions.  Serialize is virtual, an unknown number of classes inherit record, and for each value of unknown type I need a datacolumn of appropriate type, put together in a dataset.  I'll edit the question.